# Accessing script block with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script block, in the div element which is appended after html response. I want to access this block and call eval() function for this script. How can I access the script block.

I tried `$("#divId script")` , but it doesn't work.

```
<div id="divId">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // some code here
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't the script inside the div already "alive" when the page loads? I wonder why you have to access this script after when you could call the functions and/or variables inside this script from anywhere in the page...

Comment: It is "eval'd" automatically after it is appended. If you want to execute the code within `<script/>` multiple times you should wrap it in a function statement

Comment: I told the reason, I will call eval().

Comment: If you have to call eval to use the script, why do you have to put it inside a script tag? doesn't it make the script already available to be called anywhere on this document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#divId script").html()
```

If you don't trust me, click http://jsfiddle.net/VZfMd/

Answer (score 3):

`$("#divId script")` works fine for selecting the element, but here's the problem: `$("#divId script").text()` doesn't work in IE because jQuery isn't set up to handle the cross browser discrepancies of text nodes in script elements.

IE requires that you access the *.text* property of the script element, other browsers require that you access *.textContent*.  The following works for me:

```
var scr = $("#divId script")[0],
    txt = "textContent" in scr ? scr.textContent : scr.text;

eval(txt);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ffxnb/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it doesn't work in jQuery, but plain DOM should work...

```
$(document.getElementById('divId').getElementsByTagName('script')[0])
```

Comment: penguru, please read up on what jQuery is... it's not a **replacement** for plain DOM methods, it's an **extension**. You can mix the two together perfectly (if you keep track of what you're doing). If Jhong's method works, simply wrap that in a `$()` and you're done. If that isn't the problem... well, it isn't.

Comment: P.S. @penguru I agree with the others that you don't need to do this... I'm simply providing the solution you asked for.